# name is already used by an existing object

Tags: java, sql, oracle, database-metadata, ora-00955

In this code I am trying to delete the tables if they already exist every time I run the program, but the control is not going inside the `if` statements. `table1` and `table2` are present in the database. I have checked that in my database. Since its not going in the `if` statements, it's giving the following error in the last line, when I try to create the tables: `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData(); 
    String[] types = {"TABLE"};
    ResultSet rs1 = md.getTables(null, null, "table1",types );
    if (rs1.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs1.getString(3));
        statement.executeUpdate("drop table table1");
    }
    rs1.close();

    ResultSet rs2 = md.getTables(null, null, "table2", types);
    if (rs2.next()) {
        statement.executeUpdate("drop table table2");
    }
    rs2.close();
    statement.executeUpdate("create table table1(" +.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the tables `table1` and `table2` were created by your program above, then their names will have been capitalised by Oracle.  Try

```
    ResultSet rs1 = md.getTables(null, null, "TABLE1", types);
```

(and similarly for `table2`) instead.

Alternatively, if you want the tables to be created with lower-case letters in their names instead, enclose their names in double-quotes, i.e.

```
    statement.executeUpdate("create table \"table1\" (....)");
```

Answer (score 6):

I would replace this line

```
ResultSet rs1 = md.getTables(null, null, "table1",types );
```

with this one

```
ResultSet rs1 = md.getTables(null, null, "TABLE1",types );
```